# How to write a Criteria Builder for case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpa, criteria

I have this complicated Query for which I would like to build query using JPA Criteria Builder

```
select i.* 
from items i
where category = ? 
order by
(price >= ?) desc, 
(case when price >= ? then price end) asc, 
price desc limit 1;
```

I am not that familiar with Criteria Builder but have basic knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JPA does not currently support case expressions in the ORDER BY clause.

If you take a look at the arguments of [CriteriaQuery.orderBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html), the arguments must be of `Order` type and not `Expression` type.

Alternatively, you can execute this as a native SQL query then map the results to an entity through `@SqlResultSetMapping`.

Comment: although some implementations may allow it in the ORDER BY (but then vendor dependent)

Comment: @Ish AAAAh!! That's what I thought.. Because I didnt find any solution anywhere.